# Not able to get the selected date from UiDatepicker in Angular 6

Tags: angular, uidatepicker

I am using UIDatepicker for Angular 6.

```
 <section class="col col-6">
<label class="w-100"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar calendar-ico"></i>
<input type="text" class="input2 w-50" name="Transdate"
formControlName="startdate" id="startdate"
[saUiDatepicker]="{minRestrict:'#finishdate'}" placeholder="start date" />
</label>
</section>
```

I am trying to get the date from form control as follows:

```
this.form.get('Transdate').value
```

It returns empty value instead of selected date.

Answer (score 0):

Your form control is `startdate`:

```
this.form.get('startdate').value
```

You are trying to access the control, `Transdate` which does not exists in the form controls. If your control name is `Transdate` in the logic .ts then change the `formControlName` to `formControlName="Transdate"` in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry by mistake I have given transdate.  I have same issue for transdate control also.

Comment: this.form = new FormGroup({ 'startdate': new FormControl('')}); this.form.controls['startdate'].setValue(data.data);     this.form.get('startdate').value                                                                                            above code works fine but when i change the date from date picker control i am not able to get the selected date either by formcontrol on ngmodel

Comment: I think the datepicker does not emit event that's the reason why i am not able to get the selected date and do not know how to emit the event